# Failed to create shader cache entry: -2 with ChromeDriver and Protractor

Tags: automation, protractor

I am getting an error :[22396:25576:0305/212450.456:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(257)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2

Comment: Under what circumstances are you getting this error? There is very little information in this question we could use to provide a meaningful response on

Comment: @DublinDev, Just after login I get this . Below is the code snippet - OpenBrowser() {

       browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
       browser.get(this.baseUrl);
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.btnIdNext)).then(function(pageLoad){
          console.log('Login Page Loaded');
        })  √ Login Successful
[28172:28552:0305/224352.142:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(257)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
[28172:28552:0305/224352.144:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(257)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2

Comment: Can you add that error to your question text, also could you post you versions of chromedriver, protractor and whether you are using a 32 or 64 bit OS.